# How to import Azure Computer Vision Library in Android Studio

Tags: java, azure, android-studio, computer-vision

I'm having some trouble importing Azure Computer Vision Library in Android Studio. I'm coding in Java, I'm kind of new to it. On the Microsoft quickstart tutorial there is some Java code sample they use, but I can't figure out how to adapt it in the Android Studio environment. This is the page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/image-analysis-client-library?pivots=programming-language-java&tabs=visual-studio
I don't know how to add the implementation to the dependencies in my build.gradle(:app).

I get this error : Cannot set the value of read-only property 'name' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I would like to know how to turn this implementation into a more Androidish version : implementation(group = "com.microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices", name = "azure-cognitiveservices-computervision", version = "1.0.6-beta")

Thanks in advance !