# Android Studio Java SDK

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio, computer-vision

I was wondering if there is a Java SDK for Azure CognitiveServices.ComputerVision in Android Studio.
I found the SDK for Azure CognitiveServices.Speech in the microsoft documentation, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: hello, check this: https://github.com/orgs/microsoft/repositories?q=cognitive+android&type=all&language=&sort=

Comment: please check here-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191529/how-to-import-azure-computer-vision-library-in-android-studio/72199597#72199597